# Two divs with inline-block doesnt work

Tags: css

Why this two DIV dont show it inline? anything happens and the second DIV its show bottom...

```css
#mac{
display: inline-block;
background-color:#000000;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-top:130px;
height:455px;
width:50%;
}
#mac2{

display: inline-block;
background-color:#000000;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-top:130px;
height:455px;
width:50%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="mac"></div><div id="mac2"><img src="images/rocket.png"><span class="textomedio">Maximizamos tu ROI</span></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XCDsu/4/

Comment: It is inline for me...

Comment: Your code posted is different than your jsfiddler

Comment: if you run the script you can see that no its inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align:top;` to `#mac2`:

```css
#mac{
display: inline-block;
background-color:#000000;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-top:130px;
height:455px;
width:50%;
}
#mac2{
display: inline-block;
background-color:#000000;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-top:130px;
height:455px;
width:50%;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="mac"></div><div id="mac2"><img src="images/rocket.png"><span class="textomedio">Maximizamos tu ROI</span></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's one over another? The example in the answer clearly shows them side by side.